# ¿PHP no me reconoce una instancia de una clase wtf?

Tags: php, poo

Estoy tratando dediseñar un componente para mi sistema y php me  tirar error cuando paso una instancia de una clase  al constructor de otra instancia .
Tengo el codigo asi.

```
$mysqlConsulter= new MYSQLConsulter();
$consulter =new DBConsulter($mysqlConsulter);
```

ahi lo defino las instancias... aca viene el tema estoy aplicando elprincio de inversion de dependencias paraluego usar un factory entonces estoyapuntando un typehinting a una interface no a esa clase concreta .
asi

```
<?php
class DBConsulter
{
  private $consulter;

function __construct(consulterInterface $consulter)
{
  $this->consulter = $consulter;
}
```

y tengo la clase mysqlconsulter que implmenta esa interface.

```
class MYSQLConsulter implements consulterInterface
{
 private $pdo;

function __construct()
{

}
```

la cuestion es que php me tirar este error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to app\components\abstractDBConsulter\DBConsulter::__construct() must be an instance of app\components\abstractDBConsulter\consulterInterface, instance of app\components\abstractDBConsulter\mysql\MYSQLConsulter given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\HomeController.php on line 30 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\components\abstractDBConsulter\DBConsulter.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\HomeController.php(30): app\components\abstractDBConsulter\DBConsulter->__construct(Object(app\components\abstractDBConsulter\mysql\MYSQLConsulter)) #1 [internal function]: app\controllers\HomeController->index() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\core\router\Router.php(102): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\core\app.php(18): core\router\Router->routing() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\index.php(67): core\App->start() #5 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\components\abstractDBConsulter\DBConsulter.php on line 11

hasta donde entiendo el error me marca que tiene que ser una instancia de mysqlconsulter ..pero es una instancia lo estoy instanceando y pasando. 
La verdad no se poruqe me tira ese error alguno que me ayude porfavor, gracias.

Comment: Sucede que estas intanciando un objeto de la clase **MYSQLConsulter** y en el constructor de **DBConsulter** intentas recibir una interfaz, cuando en realidad debes recibir un objeto de la clase **MYSQLConsulter**, intenta cambiando eso

Comment: pero segun la guia de dependency inversion esto se peude hacer  porque estoy dependiendo de una abstraccion y no del metodo concreto.. lo vi en un ejemplo pero no se porque no funciona.. lo cambie y me manda lo mismo ahora el constructor de dbconsulter recibe un objeto de mysqlConsulter no la interface .. pero igual me sigue tirando el error

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to app\components\abstractDBConsulter\DBConsulter::__construct() must be an instance of app\components\abstractDBConsulter\MYSQLConsulter, instance of app\components\abstractDBConsulter\mysql\MYSQLConsulter given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\HomeController.php on line 30 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\components\abstractDBConsulter

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione.. lo queme faltaba hacer era agregar el `use namespace/MYSQConsulter` a la clase `dbconsulter`.